# How to use SELECT to get rows with both IN and EQUAL commands?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, union

I have a mysql table like this:

[image: nid | vid| tid]

I'm trying to get a list of `nid` values where `tid` is `19` *AND* any value from `53, 16 or 89`. As per the current table, I'd expect the query returns `10` which is `=19` (4th row) and `IN (53,16,89)` (last row).

I could get this as 2 separate queries like these:

```
SELECT nid FROM {term_node} WHERE tid IN (53,16,89)

SELECT nid FROM {term_node} WHERE tid = 19
```

(term_node is the table in screenshot). I'm using PHP for this application so I can combine results of these 2 queries to get the desired result (which is 10). But I think there could be a way to get this from a single database query.

I read about Union but honestly I don't know how to make use of it.
I hope I'm clear with the question and thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UNION` won't help you here. What you want is an intersection. Some databases have an [`INTERSECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) keyword that does what you want, but not MySQL unfortunately.

You can get what you want by using an inner join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TN1.nid
FROM term_node AS TN1
JOIN term_node AS TN2
ON TN1.nid = TN2.nid
AND TN2.tid = 19
WHERE TN1.tid IN (53, 16, 89)
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44ef1/2)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any union, this can be done easily by adding all tid in WHERE 
Try this

```
SELECT nid FROM {term_node} WHERE tid IN (53,16,89, 19)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Moyed. But I need to get list of nids where nid is equal to 19 AND in (53,16,89). 
Thanks again.